# preg_replace replace group #1

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Assume the following string:

```
@twitter @handles @hello
```

Using the code below, I can replace the strings and generate links

```
preg_replace(
    '/(?:^|[^>])(@' . $data->entities->user_mentions[$i]->screen_name . ')/',
    '<a href="https://twitter.com/' . $data->entities->user_mentions[$i]->screen_name . '">@' . $data->entities->user_mentions[$i]->screen_name . '</a>',
    $data->text
);
```

But the code above replaces group 0, not group 1.

A lot of questions on Stack Overflow show how to replace group 0 with group 1, but not the opposite.

My code isn't exactly clear so let me illustrate the problem:

group 1 looks like this:

```
@twitter
@handles
@hello
```

but group 0 looks like this:

```
@twitter
 @handles
 @hello
```

it matches the spaces and I don't want that.

Comment: Not exactly clear what the PHP values are but could you just reset the offset? `/(?:^|[^>])\K@' . $data->entities->user_mentions[$i]->screen_name . '/` I think that would make `0` what you want.

Comment: @user3783243 i edited my question

Comment: Can you just append optional whitespace in that case? `\h*` before the group

Comment: @user3783243 could do. but then i'd need to `trim()` the output. I really want to know if you can replace group 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change `(?:^|[^>])` to a *negative lookbehind* which won't consume: [`(?<!>)`](https://regex101.com/r/VUIdRZ/2)

Another option is to [use `\K` to reset](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match: [`(?:^|[^>])\K`](https://regex101.com/r/VUIdRZ/3)

*FYI*: Besides using [`preg-replace-callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) (where you can modify/return captures of any group) as far as I know `\K` is the only option to alter the full reported part [0] from regex side.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want a whitespace boundary to the left to for example not match `#@twitter`, you can also omit the capture group and use a negative lookbehind assertion `(?<!\S)`

```
preg_replace(
    '/(?<!\S)@' . $data->entities->user_mentions[$i]->screen_name . '/',
    '<a href="https://twitter.com/' . $data->entities->user_mentions[$i]->screen_name . '">@' . $data->entities->user_mentions[$i]->screen_name . '</a>',
    $data->text
);
```